# How to fill a column using another table's column in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join, database-design, multiple-columns

i have a table named tbl_employer

```
|  id  | employer |  emp_type  |
|   1  |   aaa    | GOVERNMENT |
|   2  |   bbb    |  PRIVATE   |
```

I want to join it with this table tbl_remit because the tbl_remit's data are

```
|RemitNo| id | employer |  emp_cat   |Amt_Remit|  AP_From |   AP_To  |
|  1    |  1 |   aaa    | GOVERNMENT |  20.00  |01/01/2016|01/31/2016|
|  2    |  1 |   aaa    | GOVERNMENT |  10.00  |02/01/2016|02/29/2016|
|  3    |  1 |   aaa    |            |  10.00  |03/01/2016|03/31/2016|
|  4    |  2 |   bbb    |  PRIVATE   |  50.00  |01/01/2016|01/31/2016|
|  5    |  2 |   bbb    |  PRIVATE   |  50.00  |02/01/2016|02/29/2016|
|  6    |  2 |   bbb    |            |  50.00  |03/01/2016|03/31/2016|
```

I want to fill up the missing Data from tbl_remit based on tbl_employer.

```
|RemitNo| id | employer |  emp_cat   |Amt_Remit|  AP_From |   AP_To  |
|  1    |  1 |   aaa    | GOVERNMENT |  20.00  |01/01/2016|01/31/2016|
|  2    |  1 |   aaa    | GOVERNMENT |  10.00  |02/01/2016|02/29/2016|
|  3    |  1 |   aaa    | GOVERNMENT |  10.00  |03/01/2016|03/31/2016|
|  4    |  2 |   bbb    |  PRIVATE   |  50.00  |01/01/2016|01/31/2016|
|  5    |  2 |   bbb    |  PRIVATE   |  50.00  |02/01/2016|02/29/2016|
|  6    |  2 |   bbb    |  PRIVATE   |  50.00  |03/01/2016|03/31/2016|
```

I used a Join Statement but failed.

```
SELECT r.RemitNo
     , r.id
     , r.employer
     , (SELECT e.emp_type 
          FROM tbl_employer e
         WHERE e.ID = r.ID) emp_cat
     , amt_remit
     , ap_from
     , ap_to 
  FROM tbl_remit r
  JOIN tbl_employer e 
    ON r.ID = e.ID
```

Comment: You need an `UPDATE` query since you want to modify the table.

Comment: You need update query...   "update tbl_remit set emp_cat =  (select tbl_employer. emp_type from  tbl_employer where tbl_employer. id = tbl_remit.id)  "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this will help:

```
UPDATE tbl_remit AS r
JOIN tbl_employer AS e ON e.employer=r.employer    
SET r.emp_cat=e.emp_type
```

Have in mind that if you have many records in the tables you may need add `INDEX` on employer fields in tables. I`m not 100% sure if r.id is equal to e.id and can be used for the JOIN but if it is ok then you can use this query:

```
UPDATE tbl_remit AS r
JOIN tbl_employer AS e ON e.id=r.id
SET r.emp_cat=e.emp_type
```

Your failing query in the question should look like this:

```
SELECT r.RemitNo
 , r.id
 , r.employer
 , e.emp_type
 , r.amt_remit
 , r.ap_from
 , r.ap_to 
FROM tbl_remit r
JOIN tbl_employer e 
ON r.ID = e.ID
```

Comment: not quite - in mysql you have to join before set and mysql will throw a warning if you don't provide a where clause.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, fixed it. Thanks. Yeah it will throw warning but will execute the query.

Comment: Thank you for all this solution. I thought of creating another table just to combine it I never thought of just updating the tbl_remit. I'll read more about mysql queries. and indexes. thanks again.

Comment: updated my answer with the proper version of your last select query

Answer (score 0):

You need update query

> update tbl_remit set emp_cat =  (select tbl_employer. emp_type from 
>   tbl_employer where tbl_employer. id = tbl_remit.id)